# neural network configuration using layer_dense in keras in r

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to use keras to train an ANN in r. I have an input with 165 variables and an output with only one variable. My sample set includes multiple observations. Let's say an ANN include one input layer, one or more hidden layer(s), and one output layer. Then each hidden layer can be defined by layer_dense. The "input_shape" argument is required for the first hidden layer, which equals to the # of input variables. If my understanding is correct, the "units" argument is supposed to be 1 to represent the single output variable in my example. The model defining code is provide at bottom.

But, the acc and val_acc are 0 if I set the "units" as 1; If I change it to 2 or more, I get positive acc and val_acc. But it makes no sense to me.

I then use the following code to predict. For "units" = 1, the y_predict has only one column; for "units" = 2, y_predict has two columns that I do not know how should I deal with.

```
y_predict <- model %>% predict(x_test, batch_size = 128)
```

Can anyone give me more explanation on the NN configuration using `layer_sense`? That is very appreciated.

```
model = keras_model_sequential()

model %>% layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 165)

model %>% layer_dense(units = 6, activation = 'relu')

model %>% layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'relu')
```

Comment: what loss function are you using when you compile your model? Eg. if you are using categorical_crossentropy you will need 2 columns. If you use binary_crossentropy you will need just one.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I use mean_absolute_percentage_error as the loss function. I just checked keras package file, but no information found about the output using this loss function. If multiple columns are required for this loss function, how should I understand them and use them in post-processing?

Comment: Is your single output a continuous variable, or a classification into a group/category (i.e., are you doing "regression" or classification)? If the latter, you can't use `mean_absolute_percentage_error` as your loss function; as @DanielFalbel suggests you need to use either `binary_crossentropy`, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Hi Dij, I think I am doing regression (i am new to this topic) and the output is a continuous variable. mean_absolute_percentage_error (MAPE) is a wide-used criteria in this area of study. After y_predict is obtained, I will manually calculate MAPE to say how good or bad is my prediction and model.

Comment: @Harry if you are doing regression, then you need to take out the `activation` function from the final layer. The activation function transforms the output for the purposes of interpretation by the next layer. Instead, you want the raw prediction from the last layer, untransformed, so it is in the same units as your actual values and you can calculate MAPE, or MSE, etc.

Comment: @Dij yes you are right. That makes sense to me. I take out the activation function for the last layer. However, The acc and val_acc are still zero during training. This time, the y_predict becomes normal, because previously almost half results in y_predict are 0, which is not right. Are there other places I should updated in your opinion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure what the functions are in `R` I've only used `keras` with `Python`, but it looks okay structurally... Good luck!